# Setting cell.ReadOnly has no effect

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`, where I want to disable some cells/rows with setting `ReadOnly = true`.

What could be the reason that sometimes this has no effect and the cells/rows are still editable?

Are there other possibilities to prevent editing specific rows or cells? Is it possible to prevent clicking or entering a cell?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could prevent editing with the [CellBeginEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellbeginedit.aspx) event.  If you dont want the cell to be edited, you can cancel the edit.  For example, if you only want the first column to be editable, you can do this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, 
   DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.ColumnIndex != 0) 
   { 
      e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running a `datagridview.Refresh()` after setting the readonly value to true.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that if you set the DataGridView's ReadOnly property (in code), then the columns' ReadOnly needs to be reset:

```
this.dgv.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true; 
this.dgv.ReadOnly = false; 
// Need to reset the column's ReadOnly state:
this.dgv.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
```

You can also [set whole rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.readonly.aspx) as ReadOnly